# Eliminate duplicate code in helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have built two methods in `exams_helper.rb` to use in views:

```
<% @topic_questions.each do |topic_question| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= topic_question.topic.name %></td>
  <td><%= correct_questions(@exam_result.exam_id, topic_question.topic_id) %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_percentage(ratio(@exam_result.exam_id, topic_question.topic_id), precision: 0) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Method to calculate the number of correct question of topic:

```
  def correct_questions(exam_id, topic_id)
    total = ExamQuestion.where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id).count
    correct = ExamQuestion.where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id, correct: true).count
    correct.to_s + '/' + total.to_s
  end
```

Method to calculate percentage of correctness

```
  def ratio(exam_id, topic_id)
    total = ExamQuestion.where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id).count
    correct = ExamQuestion.where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id, correct: true).count
    ratio = (correct.to_f/total).round(2)*100
    if ratio.nan?
      ratio = 0
    else
      ratio
    end
  end
```

These code is repeated:

```
total = ExamQuestion.where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id).count
correct = ExamQuestion.where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id, correct: true).count
```

How can I write these method better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, these methods should rely in your Model as their purpose is to compute data from Database. Also, by writing these methods in the Model layer, you can avoid duplication in controllers, views or view helpers.

View helpers should only be used for 'view-logic' methods, that do not make much sense outside of the view context.

**correct_questions** and **ratio** seem to be closely related to the ExamResult object, we could imagine the following implementation:

```
class ExamResult
  has_many :exam_questions

  def correct_questions_ratio(topic)
    ratio = (correct_questions(topic).to_f/total_questions(topic)).round(2)*100

    if ratio.nan?
      ratio = 0
    else
      ratio
    end
  end

  def total_questions(topic)
    #To avoid recomputing the result from db we memoize it for each topic.
    @total_questions ||= {}
    @total_questions[topic] ||= exam_questions.where(:topic_id => topic.id).count
  end

 def correct_questions(topic)
   #To avoid recomputing the result from db we memoize it for each topic.
   @correct_questions ||= {}
   @correct_questions[topic] ||= exam_questions.where(:topic_id => topic.id, :correct => true).count
 end
end
```

Memoization is a form of "caching" to avoid recomputing the same result many times. You can find many articles about it. Here is a good one : http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/09/20/a-guide-to-memoization/

Finally, you would have the following code in your view. The helper is not really necessary anymore, but you can still write a helper method to construct the "correct/total" part, taking an ExamResult instance - @exam_result - as a parameter.

```
<% @topic_questions.each do |topic_question| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= topic_question.topic.name %></td>
    <td><%= @exam_result.correct_questions(topic_question.topic) %>/<%= @exam_result.total_questions(topic_question.topic)%></td>
    <td><%= number_to_percentage(@exam_result.correct_questions_ratio(topic_question.topic)), precision: 0) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: okay, I think I have to rewrite my code for better. The `Memoization` also maybe is what I'm looking for solving problem when I need to load answers of exam first. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
scope :exam,  lambda { |exam_id|  where(exam_id:  exam_id) }
scope :topic, lambda { |topic_id| where(topic_id: topic_id) }
scope :correct, lambda { where(correct: true) }
```

In your helper:

```
def get_total_and_correct_count_for(exam_id, topic_id)
  [
   ExamQuestion.exam(exam_id).topic(topic_id).count,
   ExamQuestion.exam(exam_id).topic(topic_id).correct.count
   ]
end

def correct_questions(exam_id, topic_id)
  total, correct = get_total_and_correct_count_for(exam_id, topic_id)
  correct.to_s + '/' + total.to_s
end

def ratio(exam_id, topic_id)
  total, correct = get_total_and_correct_count_for(exam_id, topic_id)
  ratio = (correct.to_f/total).round(2)*100
  if ratio.nan?
    ratio = 0
  else
    ratio
  end
end
```

---

Sidenotes:

- it feels weird to perform this kind of db interactions within a helper.
- I first considered memoizing but ActiveRecord provides a builtin cache
- If it's in a loop consider caching the results to have them persisted amongst request because it hurts the db

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why not create a couple of methods on the `ExamQuestion` model, instead of using `where` each time?

```
class ExamQuestion
    #...
    def self.total_count(exam_id, topic_id)
        where(exam_id: exam_id, topic_id: topic_id).count
    end

    # create similar method for "correct" count
 end
```

Then, I would take these db calls out of the view altogether. I don't like calling models' database methods in the view, as it's just a nicer way of writing SQL in template files! If you can, put them in the controller action and pass them down to the view:

```
# Your controller action
@total_count = ExamQuestion.total_count(exam_id, topic_id)
@correct_count = ExamQuestion.correct_count(exam_id,topic_id)
#...
```

Finally, instead of passing exam_id and topic_id to your helpers, just pass `@total_count` and `@correct_count`. Nice and small helpers now :)

Comment: actually, `topic_id` is changed, it's in a loop, so I have to calculate for different topic

Comment: you shouldn't rely on instance variables in helpers, bad practice

Comment: That does change the situation quite a bit. I'd be interested to see whether anyone has a good solution that doesn't involve calling the model methods in a view or helper.

Comment: @apneadiving I recommend passing the instance variables to the helper method, not using them in the helper.